# comparing 2 commits in rugged

Tags: git, libgit2, rugged

I didn't find any documentation on getting the difference between 2 files in rugged.
I used the below code to commit a file using rugged

```
@repo=Rugged::Repository.new($reponame)
@sha=@repo.write('D:\Ruby\MyGitRepo\file1.txt','blob')
puts @sha
commit = @repo.lookup(@sha)
```

how can see the difference between the 2 commits of the same object in rugged?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The way to compare two commits in git relies on a diffing process.

**[brianmario](https://github.com/brianmario)** recently wrapped the diffing iterator feature of **[libgit2](https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2)**. Beware that this feature is not merged **yet**.

Below a high level example of its future usage.

```
r = Rugged::Repository.new('.')
diff = r.diff(commit1, commit2)

diff.deltas.each do |delta|
  # ...
  delta.hunks.each do |hunk|
    # ...
    hunk.lines.each do |line|
      # ...
    end
  end
end
```

See this **[pull request](https://github.com/libgit2/rugged/pull/103)** for more information about proposed diff implementation and usage.

Comment: thanks.. I did came across this post once I posted the question here.. trying it out..